# Reading integer then rest of the line as a single string from input

Tags: c++, input, newline, getline

Suppose I'm trying to read from the following input.txt

```
6 Jonathan Kim Jr
2 Suzie McDonalds
4 Patty
```

... and I want to store the first integers from every line and the rest of the strings as a string variable. This is what I have tried:

```
int num;
string name1, name2, name3;   
while ( ins >> num >> name1 >> name2 >> name3 )
{  
    // do things
}
```

Unfortunately this won't work since line 2 and line 3 only has 2 and 1 strings in a respective order so the loop will terminate at the very first loop.

Is there a way to store the rest of the strings after an integer in a **single variable**, including the white spaces? For example, string variable `name` would hold:

```
"Jonathan Kim Jr" // first loop
"Suzie M"         // second loop
"Patty"           // third loop
```

I thought about using getline to achieve this as well, but that would require me to isolate the integers from the string and I was hoping there's a better approach do this. Perhaps using a vector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the >> operator splits on a space, so you could use that to pull the integer into the variable. You could then use getline to grab the rest of the line, and store that into the variable.

Example (if you are reading from std::cin):

```
int num;
std::string name;
std::cin >> num;
std::getline(std::cin, name);
```

Comment: Don't forget to test the stream state after each transaction to make sure none of the reads failed. Tacking on an `if (std::cin) { use num and name } else { clean up and handle error }` here would be a good idea.

Comment: Wow, amazing. I thought even if we perform cin >> num, getline would pick up the integer again, but apparently, that's not true! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't use regular expressions (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) to parse (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex) the input? I think an expression something along the line of 2 subexpressions:

'^([0-1]+)\s([A-Za-z0-9_-/s]+)'

Comment: To answer your question, they probably didn't think of it or know it was possible.